# htmlで検索機能をつかうときdatabase全体,そのtable内にわける

Tags: php, html, sql

htmlで検索機能をつかうときdatabase全体,そのtable内にわけるにはどんな処理が必要ですか？

Comment: その「検索機能」は、どうやって（何で）実現されているのでしょうか？

Comment: htmlのsearchにphpでのsqlの表示によりです

Comment: もう少し具体的にコードを載せてもらえるとよいでしょう。もしコードがなければ設計に関するもの、画面イメージでもあるとより回答が得られると思います。